# Applescript get all values of Excel column

Tags: excel, applescript

I am trying to store all the values of an excel column in an array.

```
        set rangeDate to {value of range "A14:A100"}
        repeat with date in rangeDate
            if (date as string is equal to "01/01/2001") then
                log "It works"
            end if
        end repeat
```

In my Excel I do have an exact date of 01/01/2001 formatted in the specified columns. When I remove the range and it is just cell A14 (where the date is) it works. But when I include the range A14:A100 it doesn't work.

I am new to applescript, I guess that it doesn't store the values as array values and instead a string object? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 issues :

1) value of range should not be between {}, but between ()

2) 'Date' is a reserved word in Applescript, so you should not use it as the variable in the loop. I replaced it with 'myDate'.

3) instead of converting your date to string to compare with "01/01/2001", it is quicker to keep comparing 2 dates, and then, compare with the date "01/01/2001"

4) I think it is a bug (at least with my Excel version), but the rangeDate variable is not a list of dates as expected, but for me a list of list : {{01/02/01},{02/02/01},………} Therefore, each member of 'rangeDate' is not a date, but a list made on one item which is a date ! I am not sure, but it could also be that range definition could be a list of ranges... So I am using item 1 of sub list.

Anyway, script bellow is working :

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    tell active sheet of document 1
        set rangeDate to (value of range "A14:A100")
        repeat with mydate in rangeDate
            set TheDate to item 1 of mydate
            if TheDate = (date "lundi 1 janvier 2001 00:00:00") then
                log "It works"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: "I think it is a bug (at least with my Excel version), but the rangeDate variable is not a list of dates as expected, but for me a list of list : {{01/02/01},{02/02/01},………}" Not a bug, just the way Excel works. The value of a range object is (almost) always a two-dimensional array representing rows and columns. So the outer list will have one item for each row in the range while the inner lists will have items for each column: `{{r1c1, r1c2, r1c3}, {r2c1, r2c2, r2c3}, ... }`.

Comment: Since the range A14:A100 is just a single column, the list looks like this: `{{r1c1}, {r2c1}, {r3c1}, ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Quickly getting the values of a range of cells is great news! But even better is that you can fill in the values of a range by defining the value of that range. This is SO MUCH FASTER than doing it one cell at a time.

When I tried getting the value of a column (a range of cells), I received a list of lists. Each item in the list had only one value - that is the value of the cell.

To speed up complex operations, once you've got the list of values, take the process out of the "tell Excel" block and let AppleScript do the calculations. Then turn the result back into a list of lists and define the value of the range in Excel.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply a question, ensure that you are replying: it is explained how a column works and recommend to use AppleScript, but the question is how to get the values.

Comment: That’s right David. The question explains how to get the values from an Excel column using AppleScript which is not immediately obvious so I was grateful for this information. But the other very convenient aspect is being able to modify the values of every cell in an Excel column using the same method (it’s an array of arrays) which is much faster than addressing the cells individually.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem reading ranges with some cells containing #VALUE! (failed formulas). I didn't find a solution on the Internet, so I thought it would be a good idea to share my solution here. Comments & improvement are surely welcome. I'm inclined to think there is a more straightforward solution to the problem than this. :)

Getting all values with *value of range* can lead to a problem messing up the output of the script. AppleScript doesn't consider a cell's content "#VALUE!" (= *missing values*) a value since it is, well, missing. Therefore the script doesn't include the cell's content in the list of values. This obviously messes up the cell order in the values list, since it has less items than the actual range has cells. In this situation it is quite impossible to return each value to its original cell in the workbook. Adding ”of ranges” to the code includes all cells with missing values solving the problem.

N.B. The values will be displayed as a one-dimensional array. Handling multi-column ranges requires more work. Nonetheless the *missing values* are included.

```
set celVals to (value of ranges of range "A1:A4")
```

E.g. {2.2.2022, 1.1.2011, missing value, 3.3.2033}

In order to return the values back to the workbook it is required to build back the list of lists. A *missing value* will be written to its cell as an empty string. Of course the original (failed) formula can be written instead, if needed.

N.B. again. This code applies to one column situation only. A little more is needed to put back a multi-column range. I'm sure you'll manage. :D

```
set returningCelVals to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of celVals
   set end of returningCelVals to {item i of celVals}
end repeat
set value of range ("A1:A4") to returningCelVals
```

EDIT: I knew there is a better solution. Here it is:

```
set celVals to string value of range "A1:A4"
```

String value gives a two-dimensional array of values and error messages of the range. *String value* gives also e.g. cell's currency symbols, so it is perhaps not suitable to all situations.